# Targeting visitors from domain X on domain Y

Tags: javascript, cookies, cross-domain

1. I have a web product on aaa.com
2. My user has logged in to his aaa.com account and copied an aaa.com javascript snippet to his personal website on bbb.com
3. If the user has logged in to aaa.com in the last 30 days, I want to run a specific code on bbb.com (using the aaa.com JS snippet) whenever that specific user (and only that specific users) enters his own personal website

How can I do that? :)

Comment: What do you mean `and copied an aaa.com javascript snippet to his personal website on bbb.com`? You mean voluntarily? Copy-paste? And where do they paste it? In the console? In bbb.com's source code?

Comment: @galdub, Welcome to SO. It may be helpful if you explained your scenario a little better. Try providing a [ minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Good luck

Comment: I mean the user took a Javascript snippet (e.g. aaa.com/a.js) and added it to bbb.com's source code :) 
@jeremy-thille

Comment: So, the user is a developer of bbb.com's site? The solution to your problem is that bbb interrogates aaa to know if the user has logged in in the past 30 days. So, aaa should have an API or at least a specific endpoint to respond `true` or `false` to bbb. The snippet of code installed on bbb should only query this API and receive the answer.